# Having trouble with pure css parallax working on firefox

Tags: css, parallax

I've tried to create some css only parallax by using `transform: translateY()`. There are two sections and a div in the first section that go at different speeds. The button in the div in the first section is interactable on chrome but not on firefox. Here is a simplified codepen: https://codepen.io/gabestuf/pen/MWzRBQq

Is there an easy fix to this or should I try a different approach?

I've tried simplifying it down as much as possible. Adding `pointer-events: none` to the wrapper class makes the button work, but then I lose the ability to scroll and all pointer-events. I've tried changing z-indexes but nothing that solved the problem without breaking something else.